# How do you get the push object sent to iOS device from Urban Airship (Objective-c)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I am receiving push notifications from Urban Airship with custom information. It shows up on the log but I am attempting to get the object so I can parse the data to store specific value, such as 1 of "quest_id". How can I go about retrieving the object or where can I look into? Any suggestions or insight would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: So you'd like to intercept the notification once it has been received?

Comment: @Fullmetal_Alchemist_Fan Yes sir!

Comment: Did you look at - (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo delegate method in your app delegate? If you've registered your device with APNS properly then this is where you would find the incoming payload.

Comment: @Fullmetal_Alchemist_Fan Is it a method that I had to implement on my own? If so how can I go about doing so? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the push notification configuration you've made in *Info.plist*, you should implement the following methods in *AppDelegate.swift*:

```
func application(application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)
```

or

```
application(application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)
```

Here is a basic example of how you can do it:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject: AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
  if let questID = userInfo["quest_id"] as? Int {
    print(questID) // prints 1
  }
  if let question = userInfo["question"] as? String {
    print(question) // prints "What is threading?"
  }
  completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you would have to implement (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo method defined in UIApplicationDelegate.This method will be called when a push notification is received.You can then use the userInfo dictionary it will contain all the push information

Answer (score 0):

Either use the mentioned app delegate methods or since you are using Urban Airship you can set a [UAPushNotificationDelegate on the UAPush instance](http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/ios.html#handling-notifications).